# ASP.NET MVC routing specificity not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a report for my application which takes in three parameters. They include:

1. ClientID
2. SupplierID
3. Review Period ID

However, the last two parameters are optional. This means that my report is quite flexible, for example:

1. Report using ClientID and Supplier ID
2. Report using ClientID and Review Period ID
3. Report using ClientID, SupplierID and Review Period ID

So I thought that I'd be able to create a route which can handle all 3 report options. This looks like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "SupplierReportBoth",
             url: "{client}/Reports/SupplierReportSelection/{ClientID}/{SupplierID}/{ReviewPeriodID}",
             defaults: new { client = "APL", controller = "Reports", action = "SupplierReportSelection", ClientID = UrlParameter.Optional, SupplierID = UrlParameter.Optional, ReviewPeriodID = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

However, when I test my routes and try to include just one of the two parameter, it fails. It should look like this:

```
http://localhost:50408/ClientName/Reports/SupplierReportSelection/1/7
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:50408/ClientName/Reports/SupplierReportSelection?ClientID=1&ReviewPeriodID=7
```

I tried adding seperate routes which would take into account all three reports(two single searches and one multi parameter search). It did not work, instead, depending on the route I placed first. It would try to enter the parameter i'm searching with, with the incorrect parameter on the incorrect route. For example, if i searched for a supplier report, but the review period route was first. It would try to enter the supplierID as the review period ID and this wouldnt work.

Can anybody help me so I can keep one overall route which would handle all 3 types of reports?

Comment: Can you put the code of the action (SupplierReportSelection)?

Comment: I don't think you can have more than one optional route parameter - how would you represent a route where the 1st and 3rd parameters are provided but the 2nd is not? I think you either a) POST your parameters in a ViewModel object to an action marked with `[HttpPost]` and do away with URL parameters altogether, or settle for having named parameters in your query string.

Comment: @MarkE E I will settle for what it already does. At the moment, it caters for two out of three of the reports. It's not essential. It just looks better, thats all

Comment: @MarkE is correct. Only the last parameter can be marked with `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: @StephenMuecke What? So I can only have one optional parameter?

Comment: You can only have one parameter marked `UrlParameter.Optional` in your `MapRoute` definition (the last one). But of course you can have multiple optional parameters in your methods - e.g `public ActionResult SupplierReportSelection(int? ClientID, int? SupplierID, int? ReviewPeriodID)`. There is a blog describing it it more detail which I'll link to as soon as I can find it again :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't believe this is the case as I have other routes which work with two optional parameters in my route config

Comment: It wont fail, it just adds the query string values as `?xx=yy` if you only provide one of the 2 values (because there is no way of know which one of those values you are actually providing)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ahh I see, and thats my problem. It doesnt know which ID i am providing